# openlayers python proxy.cgi script is not taking parameters

Tags: python, openlayers-2, openstreetmap, proxy

I have setup the python proxy.cgi in cgi-bin folder in my server.

**[myserver]/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi** returns the **openlayers website**

**[myserver]/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=www.openlayers.org** returns **list index out of range** (www.openlayer.org is defeined in the allowed host)

**[myserver]/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url="www.openlayers.org"** returns **list index out of range** (www.openlayer.org is defeined in the allowed host)

**[myserver]/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http://www.openlayers.org** returns **page not found**

**[myserver]/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url="http://www.openlayers.org"** returns **page not found**

The proxy is working, but if i use url without http it gives list index out of range, if i use http in url the script is failing.

The url i wasnt to access is **http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/190554764** and the cross domain issue is not allowing.

Comment: Do you see anything in the apache logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode special characters (colons, slashes) in the url you want to access. In JavaScript you can use encodeURIComponent(), e.g. 
'[myserver]/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=' +  encodeURIComponent('http://www.openlayers.org')